# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first and actionfilter database call

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-web-api

This worked

I have a very odd issue going on.  I am getting the error `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.` from an API call.  This error however only happens on this one server, not the main server that also houses the database.

The code is exact, web.config is the same, except for connection string using localhost on main server.

This API call uses a session cookie attribute to validate the user.  That is the only unique thing going on here with asp.net membership.

The only thing different is the server erroring has TLS 1.0 turned off, but the main server doesnt.  I don't want to enable `MultipleActiveResultSets` either since this always worked before.  Any help would be great.

```
https://example.com/api/v1/test/help?testid=109178&_COOKIE_=<cookie>
```

Doing some logging its happening here on this filter decorated on the action for the Get method below.

**This is in the MVC action filter.**

```
var user = Membership.GetUser();

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(RoleName.ScoreKeeper.ToString()))
                        {
                            var memberId = _apiAuthenticationService.ValidUser(new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString()));

                            if (memberId > 0)
                            {
                                apiAuthorizeRequest.MemberId = memberId;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

    public int ValidUser(Guid userId)
            {
                var apiMember = _membersRepository.Get(null, q => q.UserId == userId);

                if (apiMember != null)
                    return apiMember.Id;

                return 0;
            }
```

**StackTrace**

```
Stack Trace :   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Tournaments.Data.Repositories.RepositoryBase`1.Get(Expression`1[] includes, Expression`1 where) in D:\Projects\Tournaments.Data\Repositories\RepositoryBase.cs:line 110
   at Tournaments.Services.Api.ApiAuthenticationService.ValidUser(Guid userId) in D:Api\ApiAuthenticationService.cs:line 116
```

**Inner Exception**

```
 Message :There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.  Source :System.Data  Stack Trace :   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)     at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)  TargetSite :Void ValidateConnectionForExecute(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that creates the error, there's nothing we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a concurrency problem; an `ActionFilterAttribute` gets treated as a singleton, so a single instance handles all requests.
Because of this, multiple concurrent requests share the same `_apiAuthenticationService` instance, which holds the `DbContext`. This results in the posibility that simultaneous queries/commands get executed on the shared `DbContext`instance, which fails with the given exception.

When and how often you see this error depends on the traffic of your webrequests and the speed by which queries/commands get executed by the `DbContext`/database.
*(That TLS error might already cause some delay.)*

Solution: don't use shared state within an `ActionFilter`; resolve/instantiate your dependencies separately for each request.

Comment: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ApiValidationIScoresFilter(container.GetInstance<IApiAuthenticationService>()));` is done in the Global.asax.  I want to execute some database code in this actionfilter, so how can I get around this shared state problem while using DI?  I'm also glad I found a legit answer.

Comment: Can you inject a factory method by which a new instance gets resolved/returned each time? Otherwise, I see that the framework has made quite some progress on this, but it depends on the MVC/Web API version you are on; eg. check https://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using ASP.NET Core yet and using MVC 5 with SimpleInjector as my DI.

Comment: `SimpleInjector` allows to inject a factory method/delegate http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates . Within your `ActionFilter` you resolve a new  `ApiAuthenticationService` instance via that factory method.

Comment: Got it working with a direct call to the service, not exactly what I want but dont have time to look into anything else at the moment.  Can you put this in your answer `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApiAuthenticationService>().ValidUser(new Guid(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString()));`?